# Uploading graph api result

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm new with php and with the Facebook application framework. This is my problem: I have a php application that gets some profile information from a Facebook user and from each of his friends. All these infos are in json format (retrieved by the url "graph.facebook.com + some fields + access token"). So I've got a certain number of URLs (json files) equal to the number of user's friends and I must upload these json files to my server (a free one). The pseudo-code that I use to achieve this:

- build graph.facebook.com URL with necessary fields and access token (`https://graph.facebook.com/USER-ID?fields=field1,...,fieldN&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`)
- then, for each url, I use: `file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($url))`

Last point is the problematic one. Since the token has a one-hour validity lifetime, I don't have much time to complete all the operations, and using `file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($url))` it's very time expensive.

For example: for a user with about 400 friends the application takes 40 minutes (more or less).

The fields are these:
`first_name,last_name,id,education,birthday,political,gender,hometown,relationshi‌p_status,religion,location,locations,work,interested_in,inspirational_people,spor‌​ts,likes`

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?

Thank you all!

Comment: What fields are you grabbing? Maybe these can all be retrieved with one or two Graph API calls. If not with the Graph, then I'm sure that with FQL the results can be returned with one or two FQL queries. Let us know what data you need and we can suggest an approach.

Comment: i've edited the post with the necessary fields. @madebydavid do you think that using the $facebook->api(..) is a faster way? and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this way and it is faster: instead of using the operations described in the above post, i have used:

- the facebook api: `$facebook->api(with the necessary fields)`
- then with json_encode and file_put_contents i convert the array returned by the apui and put it on the server

the question is: why this way is a faster one?